# Changing AWS Lambda environment variables when running test

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got a few small Python functions that post to twitter running on AWS. I'm a novice when it comes to Lambda, knowing only enough to get the functions running.

The functions have environment variables set in Lambda with various bits of configuration, such as post frequency and the secret data for the twitter application. These are read into the python script directly.

It's all triggered by an Event Bridge cron job that runs every hour.

I'm wanting to create a test event that will allow me to invoke the function manually, but would like to be able to change the post frequency variable when run like this.

Is there a simple way to change environment variables when running a test event?

Answer (score 0):

That is very much possible and there are multiple ways to do it. One is to use AWS CLI's `aws lambda update-function-configuration`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html

Alternatively, depending on programming language that you prefer, you can use AWS SDK that also has a similar method, you can find an example with JS SDK in this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_lambda_code_examples.html